# Get data attribute value of the Nth element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the `data` attribute value of the first element from the `elements` matched by this jQuery selector but it is giving me an error:

```
$("p.expiryItem").get(0).attr("data-id")
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).attr is not a function(…)

Yet it works with this:

```
$("p.expiryItem").attr("data-id")
```

What if I want to use the Nth element? Thanks

Comment: use `$("p.expiryItem:nth-child(1)").attr("data-id")` or `$("p.expiryItem").eq(0).attr("data-id")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because although `get(N)` returns the Nth element in the matched set, it returns the underlying DOMElement which does not have an `attr()` method and hence the error.

To fix this you could use `eq()` which does the same job, but returns the element in a jQuery object:

```
$("p.expiryItem").eq(0).data('id') // zero-based
```

Or you could use the `:nth-child` selector:

```
$("p.expiryItem:nth-child(1)").data('id') // one-based
```

Note the preferred use of `data()` here to retrieve the `data-*` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`$("p.expiryItem:nth-child(1)").attr("data-id")`

Use selector [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> note that it starts with 1
>
> Description: Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`eq(n)`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

> difference between `get(n)` and `eq(n)` is that `get` returns JavaScript reference to the element, but `eq` returns jQuery object, which has the function `attr()`.

```
$("p.expiryItem").eq(n).attr("data-id");
```

PS:

You can use `data()` function for data-attributes.

```
$("p.expiryItem").eq(n).data("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**.eq()**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) jQuery method.

Eg.

HTML :

```
<p class="expiryItem" id="1">1</p>
<p class="expiryItem" id="2">2</p>
<p class="expiryItem" id="3">3</p>
<p class="expiryItem" id="4">4</p>
<p class="expiryItem" id="5">5</p>
```

JavaScript :

```
//For 2nd `p`
console.log("Attribute value of 2nd : "+$("p.expiryItem").eq(1).attr("id"));
//For 5th `p`
console.log("Attribute value of 2nd : "+$("p.expiryItem").eq(4).attr("id"));
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jenson555/05do7438/)**